# After Effects: Custom counter expression (Tenner steps)

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I have following expression

```
Math.round(effect("Slider Control")("Slider"))
```

on a text layer to control the text with the slider and be able to make a countdown.
How can I make this in "tenner" steps, so when I add two keyframes with "300" and "0", it should countdown, but in "tenner" steps, so 300, 290, 280

Thanks..

Comment: Hi.  Video editing questions are off-topic here. Sorry about that. Might be better to ask this on Video Production Stack Exchange, or flag your own question and ask the mods to migrate it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You divide by 10, round the result, then multiply by 10.

So the formula may be:

`Math.ceil(effect("Slider Control")("Slider") / 10) * 10`

You may prefer to substitute [Math.ceil()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) with [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) or [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) for different timings.